# Searching in array return wrong result

Tags: php, arrays

I have received array like this

```
Array
(
    [hash] => 9761d3233f9cb256c0992be

    [total] => 2736712601    
    [received] => 2017-01-13T21:43:32.047Z
    [income] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [value] => 647262
                [addresses] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Address_1
                    )
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [value] => 17200000
                [addresses] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Address_2
                    )
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [value] => 3729034
                [addresses] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Address_3
                    )
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [value] => 2414997500
                [addresses] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Address_4
                    )
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [value] => 10856454
                [addresses] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Address_5
                    )
            )
     )
)
```

So in my database I store the hash (`9761d3233f9cb256c0992be`). The I hash and the address. Then based on them I match the correct array from `[income]`. When I found correct address in `income` I take the `[value]` and showing it on the page. Here is how I've made it

```
$url=get_curl_content("https://example.com/".$order->hash);

$totala =json_decode($url,true);

....
$match = true;
foreach ($totala['income'] as $data) {
    if ($data['addresses'] == $order->address) {
            $match = $data;
            break;
    }
}                     
$price = $data['value'];
```

The problem is that I'm expecting `Address_2` because in database i have saved `Address_2` I've got `Address_3` instead.

When I `var_dump($data['addresses'])` i got `Address_3`. What can be the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't be `$price = $match['value']` ?

Comment: `$match['value']` return `NULL`

Comment: what's your order content?

Comment: @KrisRoofe did you mean this `$order->address`? It's a string

Comment: It's really simple, just debug your code.

Comment: I mean what's its value???

Comment: For the order which I check is `Address_2` and I expect to match `Address_2` from the array but is matching on `Address_3`. They are totally different strings. Those are test values that's why they are Address_2, Address_3...

Comment: `var_dump($data['addresses'])` return `array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "Address_3" }`. `$order->address` return `string(9) "Address_2"`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. It will search and match in array using [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function

```
$match = true;

foreach ($totala['income'] as $data) {

    if (in_array($order->address, $data['addresses'])) {
            $match = $data;
            break;
    }                         

}                     
$price = $match['value'];
```